# Should I use "the" before file names?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

It's possible that this question has been asked before, but neither google nor stackexchange search show anything.

As in the title, do we use "the" before filenames? As in "The config.txt" or "config.txt" ? Or maybe it depends on the context, some files have "the" before them, while others don't ("the config.txt" but just "vacation_photo.png")

Comment: Please see also [ell.se]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with other names, we only use "the" when we are picking out one of several items with the same name, nearly always with some identifying words (eg "The Lincolnshire Boston" or "The Muhammad Ali who was viceroy of Egypt). Otherwise "the" is ungrammatical before a name.

So "The config.txt that was created in the previous step" would be fine, but without such a defining phrase, just "config.txt".

What might mislead you is that we *can* use a name in apposition to a definite noun phrase: "the file config.txt" is fine.